# Passport authenticate access to req

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have set up azureAD login with passport in my Express-server. I would like to access the req object in the passport.authenticate middleware, is this possible somehow?

```
this.router.post(
    'login/azure/return',
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', {
        session: false,
        failureRedirect: '' // I would like access to the req object HERE
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: did you figure out how to do it? If yes then please share

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the req object because these are default options provided based on the authentication or the configuration you want to provide to a user. For sample you can check this:

```
passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/', session: false, customState: 'my_state', resourceURL: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send'}, (req, res, next) => {
    log.info('Login was called in the Sample');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

For more information, you can check the details [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#413-options-available-for-passportauthenticate).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Look at your code, at some point you have to define your OIDCStrategy, which looks something like this:

```
var strategy = new OIDCStrategy({
  "clientID": "clientId goes here",
  // a bunch of attributes will be listed here
  "passReqToCallback": true   //  <--- this will do the trick
  }, 
  function authenticationCallback(req, iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done){  
     //  you will get "req" in this call back
    

  }
);
```

When defining the options of your strategy make sure you use the attribute "passReqToCallback": true (as shown in the example), and use the function signature also provided in the example, the first parameter will be your "req" object.